# Should I use DTO interfaces in a Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm experimenting with a web api in .NET Core 2, where I try to seperate concerns cleanly like in the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703433.aspx

One thing I am wondering about is: When using repository interfaces to set/get data, should the data types also be interfaces?

Example (reduced to emphasize the question):

```
public class ProjectController : Controller
{
    IProjectRepository _repo;

    [HttpGet]
    public IProject GetProject([FromRoute] string key)
    {
        return _repo.GetProject(key);
    }
}


public interface IProjectRepository
{
    IProject GetProject(string key);
}


// Implementation based on Entity Framework
public class EFProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
    private SomeEfContext _context;

    public IProject GetProject(string key)
    {
        return _context.Projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == key);
    }
}


public interface IProject
{
    string Key { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}


// EF specific implementation
public class Project : IProject
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My reason for doing it is, that if I don't, then the EF-implementation specific field **Id** will "bleed through" into the controller, which I do not want. As I said, this example is very simple, there are reasons for this Id field to be present - it becomes more obvious, when the example is extended with associated DTO's like "Task" etc.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Two things: unless you are completely sure you'll ditch EF in the future, it's completely pointless to create a repository layer on top of it. Second: I've never seen a `IDTO`, but that might be just me. It would be seriously weird to have a class that has an ID for EF but not for another repository, though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto great advice.

Comment: I don't think having a repository class is completely pointless like @CamiloTerevinto says. It's not ideal to leak your database model classes into the controller and you definitely don't want to be returning them down to the client out of the controller, which is what seems to be happening in your example. A repository could handle the retrieval from the EF context and then map the Project model into a ProjectDto (without the Id) and return that.

Comment: @pmcilreavy I didn't say any of that. I use a Domain layer abstracted with interfaces that return DTOs, and I have no use for a Repository layer

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It also feels wrong with IDTO, which is what made me ask here on SO. So if I understand you correctly, I should rather just have my controller layer define its own in/out DTO's, that then almost are the same as the entities used by my EF repository implementation?

Comment: @CarstenGehling Not really, DTO = data transfer object. The controller receives/returns DTOs and passes them to a Business/Domain layer that transforms them into Entities (the classes that EF use). It's quite normal to have DTOs that match exactly to Entities

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto There was some formulating errors in my previous comment, that I was too late to be able to change. But I understand what you mean, so that's the way I will do it. Do you have any good links that describes your way of working with Business/Domain layers?

Comment: @CarstenGehling Not really, but I recently adopted many patterns and practices from the book "Adaptive Code: Agile coding with design patterns and SOLID principles, 2nd Edition" by Microsoft Press. Not sure if I should post an answer with some example

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Great! Thanks a lot for your help. Please throw in an answer to get your well deserved rep, if you want. :-)

Comment: BTW no need to make it too verbose - I'll buy the book and read it anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't seen a DTO Interface, you could use it though if you have different clients with common properties. The problem I see is that you are mixing up between Entities (your Business Objects) and DTOs (what you send/receive from clients).
Normally, the Controller, being a client, would not know of the Repository layer. This should be knowledge of the service layer.
If you will only have a single data access layer that uses Entity Framework and you aren't planning on leaving it aside, I would recommend not to have a Repository layer at all, since it already implements both Repository (`DbContext`) and Unit Of Work (`DbSet`).

A standard SOLID architecture would look something like this (each being a separate project):

- Project.Core

  - Visible to everyone
  - Does not contain any reference
  - Contains your DTOs and helper classes
- Project.DataAccess

  - Visible to Domain
  - Contains your EF stuff
- Project.Domain

  - Visible to Web only for configuring DI
  - References Core
  - Receives and returns DTOs
  - It is where your business logic actually is
- Project.Abstractions

  - Visible to Web and Domain
  - Contains the interfaces of your services, which are implemented in Domain
- Project.Tests

  - References Domain and Core
  - Contains your tests
- Project.Web

  - References Domain, Abstractions and Core
  - Contains your actual Web APIs
  - Uses Dependency Injection to call Domain's services.
  - Receives either primitives (`string`, `int`, etc) or DTOs, and returns DTOs

Notice that only the domain/business layer actually sees the Entities that represent your database.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry to comment on a bit older post, but I like this architecture and I use it myself, but I was wondering where do you keep your entities in this architecture? 

It makes sense to me to keep them in the Core project, what do you think about that?

Comment: Doesn't the DataAccess should have refrences for Abstractions for DI? and Abastractions should have references for Core?